# I would like to make a python script automatically start again when computer wakes up

Tags: python

I have a python script running in the background. When my computers goes to standby/sleep it stops working. When I wake up my computer the script is not running anymore.

I would like to make it automatically start again when computer wakes up. How can I do it?

Comment: Use the script as a service in your computer.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? It does automatically start when i start my computer